# Which VCF field do I use to specify a group in Android?

Tags: contacts, vcard

I'm creating a VCF file on my website. It works nicely with the export, and most data are being imported, but the group is not created or used on Android.

I've tried using `CATEGORIES` and `ORG`. I also tried to look at `KIND` and `MEMBER`, but couldn't figure out how to use those, seems to refer to URI's and not a group name in the phone book. If I export a contact, it doesn't fill in the group in the contact.

Which VCF field do I use to specify a group in Android?

Comment: The source of the importer is mirrored here [on omapzoom](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/frameworks/opt/vcard.git;a=summary), you can look up which fields it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of valid VCard fields separated into supported/unsupported by Android's VCard importer: [VCardConstants.java](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/frameworks/opt/vcard.git;a=blob;f=java/com/android/vcard/VCardConstants.java;h=67c07b76b7dbf237d82c6dfcf91ebd1267a8b855;hb=5f55ee296e26d5278fd0d91657edddc92766459e).

As of Android 4.3, `ORG` is supported while `CATEGORIES` is not. Check it yourself for more clarification.

You may also want to compare what has changed in 4.0/4.1/4.2/4.3 [here](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/frameworks/opt/vcard.git;a=summary).